# Working with smaller text and coping with system set Dynamic Text Size changes on the Apple Watch

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I would like to know how people have reliably (from a system set dynamic text size POV) worked with smaller size fonts on the apple watch, with normal text and timer elements.

The former can have their text size assigned in their attributed text, however the preferred fonts (or descriptors) used to create the new smaller font don't seem to update their size with respect to the watch's dynamic text size setting.

The latter can't have their text size assigned directly though using their minimum text scale and resizing them in the storyboard you can shrink them to a given size ok. The problem from a dynamic text size POV is that these timers DO update their size from the dynamic text size setting but if you've used the storyboard scale and minScale route to resize them then you can run into trouble when larger text size is selected by the user and no longer fits in the smaller size frame so is truncated as ...

Essentially dynamic text size on the watch doesn't even seem to be properly exposed in any of the API so you can't even adapt UI element sizes in code depending on what the current system dynamic text size is set to.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, what's the specific question?

Comment: Please cut down on the paragraphs and explain your actual question, a wall of text makes the actual question confusing.

Comment: Should I edit this post or make a new one? Sorry it is a bit meandering.

Comment: Edited and removed the old post